# How can i offer chrome extension as paid for all users and free for selected users?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have developed a google chrome extension. I want to publish it as a "paid" extension on the webstore. However, I also want to offer the same extension for free to some users (my colleagues!).

Is there a way I could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: True not about writting code but the process of publishing code i think its fair to ask.

Comment: This is definitely on topic because there's no other place to ask— thank you for the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way i know is to publish two
One paid
One free but restricted to a google group. Put your colleagues in that google group.

The disadvantage is to publish two updates on every version change. Also existing storage will be lost for your colleagues as its a new extension

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought there would be an easier and obvious way. Finally resorted to publishing two versions :(

Comment: Is there any better solution to this problem now? It's been 4 years

Comment: yes there is. you can integrate it with an external pay service like Stripe.